# ImportTsv command is not working in Hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am using `HBase 0.98.1-cdh5.1.3`. I am trying to ingest a csv file present in my hdfs at location `/user/hdfs/exp` to Hbase. My file has data in the following format:

```
1,abc,xyz

2,def,uvw

3,ghi,rst
```

I am using the command below:

```
bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv '-Dimporttsv.separator=,' -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,CF:firstname,CF:lastname tablename /user/hdfs/exp
```

I have also used different combinations like

```
bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,CF:firstname,CF:lastname tablename /user/hdfs/exp '-Dimporttsv.separator=,'
```

and

```
bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,CF:firstname,CF:lastname '-Dimporttsv.separator=,' tablename /user/hdfs/exp
```

but nothing works. It fails to detect separator i.e , in my case and is not parsed properly. Can anybody help me figure out where I am going wrong.

this is just one line of data set:

10000064202896309897,1000006420,2896309897,10180,hdfs://btc5x015:8020/user/mr_test/logsJan/log_jan20_29/10180_log201501260000.log,3.2.3.1,9,2015-01-26,15:46:12.12,REF SHOULDER 4,n,n,SHOULDER,60,17.0,M,487093458,[study_16004_16004_],exam_16004_16004,[patient_16004_1_],Schulter std,SCHULTERGELENK RECHTS,8.10,NOT_EXIST,-8.1,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,n,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,y,n,HF,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,,,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,N,NOT_EXIST,1,NOT_EXIST,IMAG,FFE,T1FFE,4.0,0.72,34,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,4.0,cor,,NOT_EXIST,no,0,n,NOT_EXIST,1,0.0,,,,,,,NOT_EXIST,102,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,15:45:29.28,15:46:12.12,15:46:12.12,9.5,9.4,1.002,NOT_EXIST,TRUE,no,NOT_EXIST,0.0,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,0.0,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,0.0,0.09,0.3,3.3,0,false,false,n,n,26.1,LT,0.33,0.03,NOT_EXIST,null,1,Dres.GrafKernHausmann,E:\Export\DataMonitoring\p_i_20150126_154530.frame,hdfs://btc5x015.code1.emi.philips.com:8020/user/mr_test/logsJan/log_jan20_29/10180_log201501260000.log,317774,883,0,0,1,8,6,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,6014,0,15:44:08.15,15:44:59.93,15:45:23.14,15:45:29.28,00:00:00.00,00:00:00.00,15:45:30.57,15:45:38.45,15:45:29.28,15:46:12.12,15:45:38.45,15:46:12.12,42984,33967,0,7988,6014,00:00:00.00,00:00:00.00,0,00:00:00.00,00:00:00.00,0,169,102,SENSE-SHOULDER8,,SENSE-SHOULDER8/(19) BODY-QUAD,190,190,CLINICAL,0,0,94166709,Radiologische Gemeinschaftspraxis,Dr. med. Michael Graf,Dr. med. Andreas Kern,Dr. med. Hausmann,Wetzlar,35578,Hausertorstr. 47,6,NOT_EXIST,1,NOT_EXIST,NO,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,1,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NO,NOT_EXIST,SHORTEST,NOT_EXIST,SHORTEST,1,NO,YES,DEFAULT,FFE,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,3,NOT_EXIST,CARTESIAN,YES,NO,NOT_EXIST,NO,NOT_EXIST,low,FULL,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,3D,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,YES,NOT_EXIST,no,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NO,NOT_EXIST,USER_DEF,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NO,DEF,H,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NO,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,MPU_MTC_MODE_NO,NO,NOT_EXIST,T1,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NO,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,450,405,YES,Supine,HF,NOT_EXIST,NO,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,DEFAULT,NOT_EXIST,2,SENSE-SHOULDER8 BODY-QUAD,F,400 400,,,100 100,5.625,7.23214293,4,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NO,NO,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,80,PARALLEL,NO,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NO,NOT_EXIST,0,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,OFF,NOT_EXIST,NO,NO,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,0,5.625,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,NOT_EXIST,10180,15:45:29.29,15:46:13.76,null,,,96,,1,,,0,10180,PATTERN_SRN,SHOULDER,SCHULTER,MATCHED_SHOULDER,SHOULDER,UPPER EXTREMITIES,ANATOMY_GROUP_MAPPED,10180,10180,10180,3.2.3,Achieva 3.0T,Achieva,T30,3.0T,NO,F2000,Watercooled2,274-D,Master,NONE,,,0,16,0,1,S26_128,NONE,8,null,CDAS,LOGFOLDER_SYSFOLDER_MATCHED_RELEASE_NOT_CHECKED,FALSE,null,null,null,null,12.15,SENSE-SHOULDER8/(19) Q-BODY,0,SCAN_PARSE_SUCCESS,SHOULDER,-4.64757729 5.37445641,

Comment: In the above example problem i have given 3 columns but actually there are 414 columns. Is there any limit on the no of columns we can add in a single column family as I am using single column family CF

Comment: Hi, Can you please elaborate problem? Do you get any exception while running ImportTSV command? In my understanding 3rd option seems to be correct. I hope your hbase table is properly created.

Comment: First of all thanks for reply. No I don't get any error or exception while running. But at the end of MapReduce I get this 

 ImportTsv
                Bad Lines=1624286
        File Input Format Counters
                Bytes Read=5570954433
        File Output Format Counters
                Bytes Written=0
Here the Bytes Written is 0

Comment: Seems to be some issue with input data.Can you please try taking sample records from your input data and try loading into hbase?

Comment: I tried ImportTsv with 5 lines of data. Situation is still the same

Comment: There is a property -Dimporttsv.skip.bad.lines=false . You can try setting this parameter along with your ImportTSV command and see if it works for you.

Comment: 2015-08-18 15:08:53,071 FATAL [IPC Server handler 6 on 58566] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Task: attempt_1439207329121_0193_m_000000_0 - exited : java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv$TsvParser$BadTsvLineException: Excessive columns
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TsvImporterMapper.map(TsvImporterMapper.java:164)

Comment: seems there is a limitation on number of columns that we can add with ImportTsv. Is there any other way of doing it. Have tried loading data using pig but its taking 30 mins approx to insert 2.8 GB of data.

Comment: As far as I know ,if you have tsv file then this utility works fine or you can write your custom map reduce job which will do a bulk load in hbase. Above exception indicates that there is some problem with input data. Hbase should be able to handle 414 column.Can you paste sample input data ?

Comment: Have shared one line of data set in question.

Comment: Can you please accept answer if things are working for you?

Answer (score 0):

I just loaded a single line give in question into hbase table with ImportTSV command by providing 414 columns and it worked perfectly for me.Here is a command that I used.

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,CF:c1,CF:c2,CF:c3,CF:c4,CF:c5,CF:c6,CF:c7,CF:c8,CF:c9,CF:c10,CF:c11,CF:c12,CF:c13,CF:c14,CF:c15,CF:c16,CF:c17,CF:c18,CF:c19,CF:c20,CF:c21,CF:c22,CF:c23,CF:c24,CF:c25,CF:c26,CF:c27,CF:c28,CF:c29,CF:c30,CF:c31,CF:c32,CF:c33,CF:c34,CF:c35,CF:c36,CF:c37,CF:c38,CF:c39,CF:c40,CF:c41,CF:c42,CF:c43,CF:c44,CF:c45,CF:c46,CF:c47,CF:c48,CF:c49,CF:c50,CF:c51,CF:c52,CF:c53,CF:c54,CF:c55,CF:c56,CF:c57,CF:c58,CF:c59,CF:c60,CF:c61,CF:c62,CF:c63,CF:c64,CF:c65,CF:c66,CF:c67,CF:c68,CF:c69,CF:c70,CF:c71,CF:c72,CF:c73,CF:c74,CF:c75,CF:c76,CF:c77,CF:c78,CF:c79,CF:c80,CF:c81,CF:c82,CF:c83,CF:c84,CF:c85,CF:c86,CF:c87,CF:c88,CF:c89,CF:c90,CF:c91,CF:c92,CF:c93,CF:c94,CF:c95,CF:c96,CF:c97,CF:c98,CF:c99,CF:c100,CF:c101,CF:c102,CF:c103,CF:c104,CF:c105,CF:c106,CF:c107,CF:c108,CF:c109,CF:c110,CF:c111,CF:c112,CF:c113,CF:c114,CF:c115,CF:c116,CF:c117,CF:c118,CF:c119,CF:c120,CF:c121,CF:c122,CF:c123,CF:c124,CF:c125,CF:c126,CF:c127,CF:c128,CF:c129,CF:c130,CF:c131,CF:c132,CF:c133,CF:c134,CF:c135,CF:c136,CF:c137,CF:c138,CF:c139,CF:c140,CF:c141,CF:c142,CF:c143,CF:c144,CF:c145,CF:c146,CF:c147,CF:c148,CF:c149,CF:c150,CF:c151,CF:c152,CF:c153,CF:c154,CF:c155,CF:c156,CF:c157,CF:c158,CF:c159,CF:c160,CF:c161,CF:c162,CF:c163,CF:c164,CF:c165,CF:c166,CF:c167,CF:c168,CF:c169,CF:c170,CF:c171,CF:c172,CF:c173,CF:c174,CF:c175,CF:c176,CF:c177,CF:c178,CF:c179,CF:c180,CF:c181,CF:c182,CF:c183,CF:c184,CF:c185,CF:c186,CF:c187,CF:c188,CF:c189,CF:c190,CF:c191,CF:c192,CF:c193,CF:c194,CF:c195,CF:c196,CF:c197,CF:c198,CF:c199,CF:c200,CF:c201,CF:c202,CF:c203,CF:c204,CF:c205,CF:c206,CF:c207,CF:c208,CF:c209,CF:c210,CF:c211,CF:c212,CF:c213,CF:c214,CF:c215,CF:c216,CF:c217,CF:c218,CF:c219,CF:c220,CF:c221,CF:c222,CF:c223,CF:c224,CF:c225,CF:c226,CF:c227,CF:c228,CF:c229,CF:c230,CF:c231,CF:c232,CF:c233,CF:c234,CF:c235,CF:c236,CF:c237,CF:c238,CF:c239,CF:c240,CF:c241,CF:c242,CF:c243,CF:c244,CF:c245,CF:c246,CF:c247,CF:c248,CF:c249,CF:c250,CF:c251,CF:c252,CF:c253,CF:c254,CF:c255,CF:c256,CF:c257,CF:c258,CF:c259,CF:c260,CF:c261,CF:c262,CF:c263,CF:c264,CF:c265,CF:c266,CF:c267,CF:c268,CF:c269,CF:c270,CF:c271,CF:c272,CF:c273,CF:c274,CF:c275,CF:c276,CF:c277,CF:c278,CF:c279,CF:c280,CF:c281,CF:c282,CF:c283,CF:c284,CF:c285,CF:c286,CF:c287,CF:c288,CF:c289,CF:c290,CF:c291,CF:c292,CF:c293,CF:c294,CF:c295,CF:c296,CF:c297,CF:c298,CF:c299,CF:c300,CF:c301,CF:c302,CF:c303,CF:c304,CF:c305,CF:c306,CF:c307,CF:c308,CF:c309,CF:c310,CF:c311,CF:c312,CF:c313,CF:c314,CF:c315,CF:c316,CF:c317,CF:c318,CF:c319,CF:c320,CF:c321,CF:c322,CF:c323,CF:c324,CF:c325,CF:c326,CF:c327,CF:c328,CF:c329,CF:c330,CF:c331,CF:c332,CF:c333,CF:c334,CF:c335,CF:c336,CF:c337,CF:c338,CF:c339,CF:c340,CF:c341,CF:c342,CF:c343,CF:c344,CF:c345,CF:c346,CF:c347,CF:c348,CF:c349,CF:c350,CF:c351,CF:c352,CF:c353,CF:c354,CF:c355,CF:c356,CF:c357,CF:c358,CF:c359,CF:c360,CF:c361,CF:c362,CF:c363,CF:c364,CF:c365,CF:c366,CF:c367,CF:c368,CF:c369,CF:c370,CF:c371,CF:c372,CF:c373,CF:c374,CF:c375,CF:c376,CF:c377,CF:c378,CF:c379,CF:c380,CF:c381,CF:c382,CF:c383,CF:c384,CF:c385,CF:c386,CF:c387,CF:c388,CF:c389,CF:c390,CF:c391,CF:c392,CF:c393,CF:c394,CF:c395,CF:c396,CF:c397,CF:c398,CF:c399,CF:c400,CF:c401,CF:c402,CF:c403,CF:c404,CF:c405,CF:c406,CF:c407,CF:c408,CF:c409,CF:c410,CF:c411,CF:c412,CF:c413,CF:c414 '-Dimporttsv.separator=,' tablename /user/hdfs/exp
```

I have given random column name , you can update it as per your need.

**Note :** Make sure that number of columns you are passing through command are matching with your input data source. Even I got Bad Line issue when I passed 412 columns instead of 414.

Hope this will help.:)

Comment: Hi Shashi

I have already tested it this way this works but when I replace it with actual column names it throws error as I reported earlier. But this works if no of columns are small in no. Can you guide me what could be the possible error. As far as I know ImportTsv internally implements ArrayList.
Also I have tried transferring data using Hive-Hbase  storageHandler there  the length of the column SERDE_PARAMS.PARAM_VALUE is set to 4000 byte which I need to increase.
Is there any such limitation with ImportTsv also?

Comment: Hi I am not sure at this moment what could be root cause when you are working with actual columns, may be you will to start debugging to find out after which column it starts failing. For example lets say for first 100 columns load was successful but as soon as you are trying to load 101 column it starts failing,this means that there is a problem with 101st column.It will be a time consuming process but you will get root cause for your problem....Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. It looks like the single quotation is misplaced while specifying separator. Try using this: `-Dimporttsv.separator=','` instead of `'-Dimporttsv.separator=,'`
2. If the input file is prepared such that any column value consists of a field delimiter (in this case, comma), it will fail. Better to keep a different delimiter (such as |) while preparing the CSV file